# SQL aggregate function to apply average pooling for column of array<double> type

Tags: sql, hive

I have a column which is an array of double values. Is there any Hive SQL function to aggregate the column values through average pooling.

TABLE_A E.g.

```
id     vector
1     <1.0, 2.0, 3.0>
1     <2.0, 2.0, 3.0>
2     <1.5, 1.2, 2.3>

SELECT 
    id,
    AVG_POOL(vector) as pooling_vector
FROM 
    TABLE_A
GROUP BY 
    id

Expected output: 
 id     vector
 1     <1.5, 2.0, 3.0>
 2     <1.5, 1.2, 2.3>
```

The expected output pooling_vector is an array that the i-th value: pooling_vector[i] = AVG(vector[i])

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.